# evaluate module in another module's context

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that this is very un-Node/CommonJS-y—forgive me. (I'm writing a library of sorts and I'd like my library's `require` method to work exactly the same on the browser and on NodeJS.)

What I'd like is to be able to do is evaluate the script in the context of the current module—that is, if I say `exports.a = "100";` in the module, I'd like for `exports.a` to be equal to `"100"` in all of the code in the `require`ing module after the `require`.

If this isn't clear, I'd be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be a complete answer, but hopefully will help you get in the right direction.

I've been messing with Node's system of creating modules for the last couple of days. Basically I wanted to create some modules that were invoked in an entirely fresh context and variable scope, for which I would define a limited subset and extension of Node's capabilities.

I ended up studying [their source here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js), and giving particular attention to the `NativeModule` constructor and its methods.

You'll notice that the source of the module is read from a file, wrapped in a string representing a function and eval'd into actual code.

*The wrapper:*

```
NativeModule.wrapper = [
   '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, define) { ',
   '\n});'
];
```

The function is invoked, which invokes the contained module code.

The function requires half a dozen arguments as you can see from the wrapper, the first of which is the `exports` object (which starts off empty). It's also is passed the `require` function, which is why you can access `require` as a variable even though `require` isn't global.

The module code populates the `exports` object and then the `exports` is cached so all that work doesn't need to be done in the future. So when `require( 'someModule' )` is invoked, it just looks up the cached `exports` object and returns it.

I'm sure you could do something like this in your code as long as you can get the source for the module that you want to *require*.

Perhaps `SomeModule.toString()` will be sufficient for you. Not sure how consistent browser support is though.

---

There's also a private API that's used to set up the environment for the modules.

```
process.binding('evals').Script

/*
{ [Function: Script]
  createContext: [Function],
  runInContext: [Function],
  runInThisContext: [Function],
  runInNewContext: [Function] }
*/
```

I ended up needing to use `createContext` and `runInContext` to get things working, but I'd guess you probably won't need anything like this.

Comment: Want even more flexibility? read and find the private API of [REPL](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js) and then use REPL to build your own sandbox.

Comment: You're the man @Raynos! That's exactly what I need. They're the same functions, I just didn't know it was public. I came across them from the source, and didn't look to hard for them in the docs. I'm so glad to hear that it's part of the API!!!

Comment: The REPL is pretty neat. It's basically a VM with an input / output socket you can read and write to. Put it in a child process and you've got a nifty sandbox going. And as always if you think "Hey, wait a second, this should be easier" Come ask [us](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js)

Answer (score 0):

> (I'm writing a library of sorts and I'd like my library's require
>   method to work exactly the same on the browser and on NodeJS

If I understand you correctly(please forgive me if not ;)) you are looking for something like [node-browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

> Browserify Browser-side require() for your node modules and npm
>   packages
>
> Just point a javascript file or two at browserify and it will walk the
>   AST to read all your require()s recursively. The resulting bundle has
>   everything you need, including pulling in libraries you might have
>   installed using npm!